# Order columns in Bootstrap 4 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 order-2">1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 order-1">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 columns which I want to order in different ways on desktop and mobile. Order-1 works fine on mobile. But it works on desktop too. Help me to change order only for mobile view in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is *mobile first*. You will need to add a different class for larger displays.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 order-2 order-sm-1">1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 order-1 order-sm-2">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Grid breakpoints are based on minimum width media queries, meaning they apply to that one breakpoint and all those above it (e.g., .order-sm-* applies to small, medium, large, and extra large devices, but not the first xs breakpoint).

---

Note that you have the classes `order-2` and `order-1`. These classes are the same as `order-xs-*`.
So, if you want special rules only for large displays (`lg` and `xl`), just add the classes:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 order-2 order-lg-1">1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 order-1 order-lg-2">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you only want to change the order for large (`lg`) screens and above (`xl` as well), just change the `order-sm-*` to `order-lg-*` for the ordering.

Comment: The classes without prefix (order-1 & order-2) is the default for the smallest screen (eg, the same as order-xs-*).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do this...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 order-md-2">1
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 order-1">2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/1niA4HHVoV